# Scope of javax.jms.Queue in a managed context

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

I'd like to know what is the expected scope of a `javax.jms.Queue` in a a java EE managed context.

Is it a good practice to keep reference of `Queue` instances locally or should I resolve it each time I post a message.

I suppose keeping the reference is better than multiple jndi lookups as you often see code like this in stateless beans :

```
@Resource(lookup = "jms/QueueName")
private Queue queue;
```

Anyway I'am currently experiencing problems (`XA operation failed Cannot start, session is already doing work in a transaction XidImpl`) using cached  `Queue` instances resolved using `javax.jms.Session#createQueue("queueName")`.

This leads me to another question, is there a difference between resolving the queue using a jndi lookup or using `Session#createQueue("queueName")`;

Comment: Why do you think local JNDI lookups are expensive?

Comment: Who said it was local ?

Comment: What is `jms/QueueName` pointing at?

Comment: This is just an example, As I said queues are not resolved using JNDI but with session#createQueue("queueName"), references are stored in a concurrentHashMap and reused later with other sessions, code was here before me and I don't really know why it has been implemented like this

Comment: The JMS server is a remote Jboss who just host a bunch of different JMS queues, Client is a Spring singleton bean which manually lookup a local managed ConnectionFactory (yes spring app running in Java EE container, don't ask me why :)

Comment: You can find a deployment diagram here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500395/jms-topology-queue-with-multiple-consumers-and-message-grouping