# Large delays in consumption of grouped messages in ActiveMQ Classic

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We have a network of brokers consisting of three brokers on different servers.
The network connectors are configured as follows:

```xml
<networkConnectors>
   <networkConnector uri="static:(ssl://broker2:61616,ssl://broker3:61616)" networkTTL="5"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

The overall setup looks like what is shown in the image below.

[image]

In practice we sometimes see large delays for the message consumption of a specific client. In that case, messages are forwarded multiple times to other brokers before finally being consumed. Until now, we have been unable to find out what might be the cause of this.

The consumers are not very busy. They are implemented using the Spring JMS library. The minimum number of consumers is 3 per broker, but this can automatically scale depending on the need.

We suspect that the reason that only a specific client is impacted, might have something to do with the fact that we use the JMSGroupId to get some ordering in how the messages are handled. However, we have no sure proof of this. And it still doesn't explain why it happens at all.

We are also considering to add the following parameters to the network connector as we think this might improve the behavior:

```
dynamicOnly="true"
decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true"
```

However, it is also scary to do as we feel we do not fully understand what is happening right now and so cannot really be sure of the effect these settings will have on the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We suspect that the reason that only a specific client is impacted,
> might have something to do with the fact that we use the JMSGroupId to
> get some ordering in how the messages are handled.

Bingo.

Scaling consumer is useless if your ensure serial message processing. The best way to get rid of this behavior is to set up a dedicated JMS queue with a single consumer per group, otherwise you will experiment consumer contention when multiple following messages in the queue belong to the same group.

See [JMS topology (Queue with multiple consumers) and message groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33500395/2087640)

Comment: Thanks for this confirmation. What is your take on the properties I mentioned? Some blog posts say they should be added to improve the network-of-brokers behavior. The official documentation is not really clear (neither on this point nor many others).

Comment: Your problem isn't related to the network configuration at all but to the JMS implementation of serial processing. Anyway I wonder why you are using group. Do you really need to *ensure* serial processing ? messages are dequeued in natural fifo order anyway, groups are just here to mitigate multiple consumer parallelization hazard in message processing order (one consumer may consume faster than another and so commit first an operation started later), at the price of about loosing all parallelization capability.

Comment: Thanks. I figured the network configuration was not the problem, but nevertheless we were wondering if these parameters would perhaps be beneficial. Anyway, no we do not need the ordering. We thought we did, but we've come to realize that isn't the case. So we can just do away with the message groups.

Comment: I'am not competent about that, sry :) try it, and see