# Correct way to set up ActiveMQ network of brokers

Tags: activemq-classic

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205379/large-delays-in-message-consumption-of-messages-in-activemq), we have a network of brokers consisting of three brokers on different servers.
The network connectors are configured as follows:

```
    <networkConnectors>
      <networkConnector uri="static:(ssl://broker2:61616,ssl://broker3:61616)" networkTTL="5"/>
    </networkConnectors>
```

We are also considering to add the following parameters to the network connector as we think this might improve the behavior (due to advise on this [blog post](https://medium.com/thg-tech-blog/multi-data-centre-message-brokers-with-activemq-28495046370e)):

```
dynamicOnly="true"
decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true"
```

However, it is also scary to do as we feel we do not fully understand what is happening right now and so cannot really be sure of the effect these settings will have on the behavior. The official documentation is not really clear on this (neither on this point nor many others by the way).

**UPDATE:**

What we want to achieve is that messages are as much as possible handled on the broker where they first arrive. Clients (as shown in the other post) are connected via Wifi, but have a fallback to 4G. In practice, we see that they regularly switch network and therefore connect to a different broker. We want to limit the traffic over the network connectors.

Comment: I don't think there's an absolutely "correct" way to set up a network of brokers as evidenced by the fact that those configuration elements exist in the first place. It really depends on your use-case (which you haven't really explained). Perhaps you should just have questions which ask what each of those configuration elements specifically do and what the pros/cons are.

Comment: Hmmm, it's hard to ask the right question ;-) So what we want to achieve is that messages are as much as possible handled on the broker where they first arrive. Clienst (as shown in the other post) are connected via Wifi, but have a fallback to 4G. In practice, we see that they regularly switch network and therefore connect to a different broker.

Comment: You should update your question with this explanation rather than adding it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings should get you that 'prefer local' behavior you want:

decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true"

Also, add messagTTL = 4 and consumerTTL = 1. This allows messages to hop around n + 1 times. (Where n is the number of brokers in your cluster). Also, consumerTTL = 1 means brokers will only see consumers from their immediate peer, and not see over multiple hops.

In your use case, drop the networkTTL setting-- messageTTl and consumerTTL replace it and give you more control over message hops and consumer awareness.

Comment: And what about `dynamicOnly`? Is that helpfull?